# Increase VNC File Transfer Speeds

Tags: lan, file-transfer, vnc, ultravnc

I have noticed that the UltraVNC upload file transfer speed (client -> server) over a LAN is reliably about 7kb/sec no matter the conditions. Interestingly, the download file transfer speed (server -> client) is a little faster, but nothing to brag about - if that's the type of thing you brag about. The problem is even worse over WLAN, as expected. In either case, both LAN and WAN should support decent transfer rates. I read this [post](http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?t=27336) regarding changing the sendbuffer and maxcpu variables in the config file, but I see no such variable and I'm not sure if it should be created since it says that is available beginning in versions previous to the one I am using. Also, the poster reported better transfer speeds after playing with the config variables, but they were still far from what you might expect given the bandwidth in today's devices. So additional suggestions are eagerly welcome.

**The remote viewing is decent, but I am looking for any suggestions to help increase the overall file transfer speed.**

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to make any changes to the configuration file then the only other way to speed it up is to lower the resolution of the desktop you are viewing before sending it and/or by compressing your file first. Until engineers that work on UltraVNC make transfer changes themselves, you're out of luck.

On a side note, you can add those things into your configuration file and see if your speeds increase, if not, or, if the program no longer runs, then you simply remove the variables that you added to try and speed it up, save it again and it will be back to normal.

On another side note, try using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), it's free for personal use and ultimately faster on viewing. Also without any configuration to any files, you'll start out with max display settings with a transfer speed around 60k. Much faster already than your ~15k you're most likely getting with UltraVNC.